# Add extension to Midori browser

Tags: midori

I'm trying to add an extension (in crx format) to *Midori*, but I can't because the documentation is **outdated** and doesn't give info on how to add an extension that isn't written in vala. Could anyone help me?

I'm working with the build of the [repo](https://github.com/midori-browser/core) on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS